# C++ initializer list overload disambiguation

Tags: c++, initializer-list, compiler-bug

I have a question about C++ initializer list disambiguation which exhibits different behaviors between gcc, clang and Visual Studio.

I wonder if this is "undefined behavior" (incorrect program) or if one of these compilers has a bug. Any idea?

Consider the following declarations:

```
class Arg
{
public:
    Arg(int i);
};

class Object
{
public:
    Object(const char* str, int i);
    Object(const char* str, const std::initializer_list<Arg>& args);
};
```

And now this usage:

```
Object c("c", {4});
```

Which constructor should be used? The one with `int` (assuming that the braces around the literal are superfluous) or the one with the initializer list (with implicit conversion from `int` to `Arg`).

GCC 10.2.0 chooses the constructor with the initializer list of `Arg`.

Clang 11.2.2-2 chooses the constructor with `int` and reports a warning about the braces:

```
initlist.cpp:46:19: warning: braces around scalar initializer [-Wbraced-scalar-init]
    Object c("c", {4});
                  ^~~
```

Visual Studio 2019 16.8.6 chooses the constructor with `int` without warning (`/W4`).

On a majority standpoint, the constructor with `int` wins. On the other hand, if we directly use `std::initializer_list<int>` instead of `std::initializer_list<Arg>` (no implicit call to `Arg` constructor), all three compilers choose the constructor with the initializer list.

Because of the ambiguity and the difference of behavior, this kind of code should be avoided anyway. But I am curious to understand who is wrong? The undefined application code or one of the compilers?

Full source code below, in case anyone wants to try:

```
#include <iostream>

class Arg
{
public:
    int value;
    Arg(int i);
};

class Object
{
public:
    Object(const char* str, int i);
    Object(const char* str, const std::initializer_list<Arg>& args);
};


Arg::Arg(int i) : value(i)
{
    std::cout << "Arg(" << i << ")" << std::endl;
}

Object::Object(const char* str, int i)
{
    std::cout << "Object(\"" << str << "\", " << i << ")" << std::endl;
}

Object::Object(const char* str, const std::initializer_list<Arg>& args)
{
    std::cout << "Object(\"" << str << "\", {";
    bool comma = false;
    for (auto it = args.begin(); it != args.end(); ++it) {
        if (comma) {
            std::cout << ", ";
        }
        comma = true;
        std::cout << it->value;
    }
    std::cout << "})" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Object a("a", 1);
    Object b("b", {2, 3});
    Object c("c", {4});
}
```

With GCC:

```
Object("a", 1)
Arg(2)
Arg(3)
Object("b", {2, 3})
Arg(4)
Object("c", {4})
```

With clang and VS:

```
Object("a", 1)
Arg(2)
Arg(3)
Object("b", {2, 3})
Object("c", 4)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`{4}` to `const std::initializer_list<Arg>&` is a user-defined conversion.

`{4}` to `int` is a standard conversion.

The latter wins. This is a GCC bug.

List-initialization to an `initializer_list` beats others when the conversion sequences are of the same form. They are not here.

Comment: Thanks, this is clear. It is a pity that braces around a literal are accepted as the literal itself. It makes harder to disambiguate between aggregates and elementary types. Intuitively, `{4}` is perceived as a structured type, an aggregate, not an elementary type. Anyway, that is the rule...